# Unable to bind event to datetimepicker in javascript

Tags: jquery, django, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I'm running django-bootstrap-datepicker-plus==3.0.5.

I'm attempting to bind an event to the datetimepicker so that that on a certain action, an attribute changes. The list of attributes that can be changed are found here:

https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

As the page above shows, I should just be able to use the following code to set inline to true (note: I'm able to set this attribute to true on the initialization of the form in forms.py and it works fine).

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

    $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({    
    inline: true
    });

 });
```

Unfortunately, this code doesn't do anything. Should I be using '.datetimepicker' in the code above? Is there anything different about the django version of this datetimepicker that is causing this code not to work?

Not sure if this makes a difference, but the following code does work:

```
 $('.input-group').on("dp.change", function(e){        
   console.log('There was a change to the date');  
 });
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: get rid of the trailing comma

Comment: Tried this. 0 effect. Thanks though.

Comment: I ran into a pretty serious bug with datetimepicker in that it adds the same ID to multiple inputs, so if you have more than 1 on the page you can have this happen. It requires you to explicitly choose your ids in your form attrs

Comment: Thanks. I had added an id to the input-group and selected based on that. Didn't help unfortuantely :( I might try something else though. thanks for the help!